# Qt Online Installer taking too long

Tags: windows, qt, windows-10

I have started Qt setup 10 hours ago:

[image]

and it is still running:

[image]

Numbers are jumping, progress bar is progressing but very slow.

Internet speed is 750 Mbps. I am easily downloading movies and training corpora of many gigabytes in minutes.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

Online Installer uses random mirrors which can be slow to download. Try using qt mirror-list and insert the mirror which is closer to you in command line.

```
dir-to-installer:"<online-installer-filename> --mirror <mirror-HTTP-link>"
```

Documentation: https://wiki.qt.io/Online_Installer_4.x#Selecting_a_mirror_for_opensource

Mirror list: https://download.qt.io/static/mirrorlist/

Video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0BwCNKAx80

It works with Qt's Maintenance Tool too.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following suggestion and it works for me, thank you.

As a feedback I tried maintenance tool as below under Windows:

```
cd C:\QT
.\MaintenanceTool.exe --mirror <mirror-HTTP-link>
```